# How can I assign a value using if-else conditions in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe with a column a. I would like to add a different column 'b' based on column 'a'.

```
For: if a>=10, b='double'. Otherwise b='single'.
```

How can I do it?

Sample output:

```
a b
2 single
2 single
4 single
11 double
12 double
12 double
45 double
4 single
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to act on vectors with if statements.

```
ifelse(a>=10, "double", "single")
```

So your code could look like this

```
mydata <- cbind(a, ifelse(a>10, "double", "single"))
```

(Specified in comments below that if a=10, then "double")

Comment: Where do you set the default for a=10? I should have mentioned double for greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: Since if `a=10`, then `a>10` is false, so the expression evaluates to `"single"`.

Comment: Also, where do I set it to column name b? *Got it*. Never mind*

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, if-else is assignable in r, that is

```
x1 <- if (TRUE) 1 else 2
```

is legit. For details see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/control-flow.html#choices

However, as this vectorizes over neither the test condition nor the value branches, it's not applicable to the particular case described in the question details, which is about adding a column in a conditional manner. In such a situation `ifelse` or the more typesafe `if_else` (from `dplyr`) can be used.